# Zooming in result in horizontal scroll bar

Tags: google-docs

I need to have two windows with a document in Google Drive open side-by-side on a laptop, with whole text column visible at larger-than-default zoom.

The problem is horizontal scroll bar appearing on larger zooms, as Docs don't re-flow the text for current window size, but show it exactly as it will fit into paper width (see the right edge of either window):
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I found so far is: set right margin in Google Docs menu File>Page Setup (for a chozen zoom level, find a right number through trial-and-error).

Obvious downsides:

- you have to remember to restore margins before printing
- if you change zoom level, you need to change margins
- there's no instant switch between "fit to window" and "see how it will look for paper width" modes